# ASP.NET Core on Azure WebApp crashes because of SQLite

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, webapp2

I am trying to run HealthChecks UI [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) in my ASP.NET Core WebAPI. All works fine on local, but when I deploy to Azure WebApp whole application dies. When I remove the UI from the services in the Startup, all is fine, so I got to conclustion that HealthChecks UI is crashing.

It uses SQLite to store data, so I suspect at this part. I connected via SFTP to the WebAppp where I deployed it and I can see that the SQLite database file is created but has 0 bytes content.

At first I thought it might be problem with Linux host, but app dies on Windows WebApp as well when this package is used for displaying the health checks.

Any clue what might be the issue?

Comment: Try to get some logging output from Azure WebApps. This might give you some more information about what exactly goes wrong. The logs might be somewhere on Kudu (https://yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: I am running into the same problem and after enabling some logging i am finding that the sqlite database is locked :? was any progress made on your end?