# SQLite error "database is locked" when publishig on linux azure app service (.net core 3.1). But i am not using SQLite

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

When the application is published on windows it works perfectly. I am not using SQLite, I´m using SqlServer.

Error log from azure:

```
2020-11-27T17:36:08.879028391Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-11-27T17:36:08.879035191Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2020-11-27T17:36:08.879041791Z ASP .NETCore Version: 3.1.8
2020-11-27T17:36:08.879048191Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-11-27T17:36:09.077744493Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -userStartupCommand '' 
2020-11-27T17:36:09.582281718Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2020-11-27T17:36:09.583285560Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2020-11-27T17:36:09.583308261Z Build Operation ID: cf1c55c9-70a7-4bd1-bfa2-e3a2350cf36c
2020-11-27T17:36:10.816104146Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-11-27T17:36:11.085709074Z Trying to find the startup DLL name...
2020-11-27T17:36:11.086560810Z Found the startup D name: Digibyte.API.dll
2020-11-27T17:36:11.088017070Z Running the command: dotnet "Digibyte.API.dll"
2020-11-27T17:36:47.812986572Z [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
2020-11-27T17:36:47.813053275Z       Failed executing DbCommand (30,042ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
2020-11-27T17:36:47.813066676Z       PRAGMA journal_mode = 'wal';
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944070916Z Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (SQLite Error 5: 'database is locked'.)
**2020-11-27T17:36:47.944105917Z  ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 5: 'database is locked'.**
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944116518Z    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944124918Z    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944132618Z    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944140519Z    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944148119Z    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944155719Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944187521Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Create()
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944197721Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.CreateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944205421Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944213022Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944220422Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944229022Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944236223Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944243123Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHealthChecksUI(IServiceCollection services, String databaseName, Action`1 setupSettings)
2020-11-27T17:36:47.944250523Z    at Digibyte.API.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/Digibyte.API/Startup.cs:line 177
```

Comment: Can you show us the code near line `177` or all the code in your `Startup.cs` file?

Comment: `2020-11-27T17:36:47.944250523Z    at Digibyte.API.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/Digibyte.API/Startup.cs:line 177`, This sentence should point out the problem, we need to confirm it before we know the specific reason. Under normal circumstances, your error message will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

With the tip posted by @jason-pan I´ve found that the error was caused by HealthChecks package.

https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/455

Related to: [ASP.NET Core on Azure WebApp crashes because of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280065/asp-net-core-on-azure-webapp-crashes-because-of-sqlite)